CSS not loading in PDF generated using Grover gem in production mode
I am using grover gem to generate PDF from HTML template. Its working fine locally, but PDF looks UI less on production environment. I am using AWS cloudfront as CDN in production mode.
Here is a snippet of my code.
def download
  file_export = file_exports.find_by_guid!(params[:id])

  grover = Grover.new(file_export.data, format: 'A4')
  send_data(grover.to_pdf,
            filename: "#{file_export.sanitized_file_name}.pdf",
            type: 'application/pdf')
end

Here file content is generated using.
  file_content = action_controller.render_to_string(
    template: 'performance/reviews/combine_print',
    layout: 'pdf_layout',
    formats: [:html],
    locals: { data: @data, current_state:, participants:, current_user: current_state.user,
              current_company: current_state.company },
    assigns: { permissions:, make_anonymous: }
  )

Please suggest how to fix this UI difference.

Have you tried basic debugging like actually looking at the rendered markup and the paths to the CSS assets?

Do you include CSS files in your pdf_layout.html.erb ?
